# Vertx unit-test blocking the main thread

Tags: java, vert.x

While trying to test a *Vert.x* verticle using the event bus through a test class, I'm getting an "blocking errors". Here down the verticle and test classes:

`EventBusReceiverVerticle`:

```java
public class EventBusReceiverVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public EventBusReceiverVerticle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void start() {

              vertx.eventBus().consumer("geo-service", (Message<JsonObject> handler) -> {
            {
                try {
                    System.out.println("sleep 10 seconds");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }           
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The test class:

```java
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MyFirstVerticleTest {
    Vertx vertx;
    EventBus eb;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyFirstVerticleTest.class);


    @Before
    public void setUp(TestContext context) {
        logger.info("@Before");
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        eb = vertx.eventBus();

        Async async = context.async();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new EventBusReceiverVerticle("R1"), res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                async.complete();
            } else {
                context.fail();
            }
        });
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
        logger.info("@After");
        Async async = context.async();
        vertx.close(event -> async.complete());
    }


    @Test
    public void testEventBusVerticle(TestContext context) {
        Async async = context.async();
        JsonObject msg = new JsonObject("{\"action\":\"pos\"}");
        eb.send("geo-service", msg, reply -> {
            if (reply.succeeded()) {
                async.complete();
            } else {
                context.fail();
            }
        });
        async.complete();
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:23 PM com.company.MyFirstVerticleTest
INFO: @Before
sleep 10 seconds
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:24 PM com.company.MyFirstVerticleTest
INFO: @After
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:27 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 2790 ms, time limit is 2000
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:28 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 3794 ms, time limit is 2000
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:29 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 4796 ms, time limit is 2000
Sep 05, 2015 2:20:30 PM io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker
WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-2,5,main] has been blocked for 5799 ms, time limit is 2000
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.company.verticals.EventBusReceiverVerticle.lambda$start$1(EventBusReceiverVerticle.java:35)
    at com.company.verticals.EventBusReceiverVerticle$$Lambda$10/2029238960.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl$HandlerRegistration.handle(EventBusImpl.java:1108)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl.lambda$doReceive$189(EventBusImpl.java:755)
    at io.vertx.core.eventbus.impl.EventBusImpl$$Lambda$17/1888442711.handle(Unknown Source)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$15(ContextImpl.java:314)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl$$Lambda$9/911312317.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to set the verticle as a worker by setting:

```java
new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true)
```

Comment: just curious what did you use for logging. I was using JUL supplied with vert.x and nothing in my Test class was written out. When I switched  to log4j it can't seem to find my log4j.xml file.

Comment: You just need to put on your classpath log4j

Comment: This is a great answer, but I had to look up where to put it. Use when deploying a verticle as the second parameter: For example `vertx.deployVerticle("com.psi.cassandra.CassandraVerticle", new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));`

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to increase the timeout

```java
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions(); 
options.setMaxEventLoopExecuteTime(Long.MAX_VALUE);
vertx = Vertx.vertx(options);`
```

Comment: You shouldn't block the main thread. Setting the timeout to Long.MAX_VALUE can create all sorts of undesirable problems. If you have terrible blocking calls you won't even know. Avoid this solution.

Answer (score 1):

A key sentence in the [Vertx documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#_don_t_block_me) is

> Don’t block me!

You are getting the blocking message since you do execute blocking code in your Verticle. Calling `Thread.sleep(10000)` blocks your current verticle for 10 seconds.

Declaring your Verticle as a worker is a workaround. Take a look in the Vertx documentation *[Executing blocking code](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/groovy/#blocking_code)*. According to the documentation you could tell Vertx to execute `Thread.sleep(10000)` as blocking code.

```
vertx.executeBlocking({ future ->
  // Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
  Thread.sleep(10000)
  future.complete(result)
}, { res ->
  println("The result is: ${res.result()}")
})
```

Maybe you can explain the purpose of your test and why you use `Thread.sleep(10000)`?